# How to export a report of contacts with status history not changed in one year

Tags: salesforce

here we need to export a report of contacts in which status has not been changed from past one year. Is it possible to do so and if possible please let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: What's "status"? Your custom field that has history tracking enabled? In your org's setup -> sharing settings what do you have for contacts? "Controlled by parent" (= account) or something else?

Comment: Status is a field in contact object but history tracking was not enabled, do we have any other options to extract a report.

Comment: without field history tracking? Unlikely. Can you compare data to last year. Like you have backups maybe or data migration runs. Compare with full copy sandbox's data? Can you think of any side effects that happen when you change status (email sent, task created, chatter post maybe) to try to identify them that way? I mean you could go `WHERE LastModifiedDate < LAST_N_DAYS:365` but that won't be accurate at all.